# Bii code seem to damage my cmake

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, biicode

I've installed bii (v1.11) on my Ubuntu 14.10 (64bit) and while `bii setup:cpp` it downloaded and installed CMake 3.0.2. Now, when I want to use CMake from the console I get a segmentation fault:

```
$ cmake --version
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in
/home/lars/.biicode_env/cmake-3.0.2-Linux-64/bin
[1]    2993 segmentation fault (core dumped)  cmake --version
```

I need to sudo the command in order to make it function properly:

```
$ sudo cmake --version
cmake version 3.0.2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

Any suggestions how to repair this?

Comment: Have you followed the install instructions? For example, the Travis CI machines are Ubuntu x64 too, and doing the `wget http://apt.biicode.com/install.sh && chmod +x install.sh && ./install.sh` as mentioned in the docs (Without sudo) works perfectly. [Here](https://github.com/Manu343726/edalib/blob/master/.travis.yml) is an example.

Comment: I downloaded the .deb file provided from the website and `sudo dpkg -i ....deb` installed it without any errors. Then I've setup cpp as the documentation describes.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the .deb, we are working on it. We are still on beta, so feedback like this helps a lot. Thank you! Uninstall it and try with the `wget...` shown above.

Comment: Have you executed `bii setup:cpp` using sudo?

Comment: No. I executed it as normal user.

Comment: Please execute `sudo chown -r YOUR_USER:YOUR_USER /home/YOUR_USER/.biicode_env`. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

sudo `chown -R YOUR_USER:YOUR_USER /home/YOUR_USER/.biicode_env` solves the problem